# Magento - show custom selector on frontend

Tags: php, magento

How to show the custom selector on the Frontend so that it would work like a store switcher and/or a language switcher. 
Similar to the "Panel Tool" option on the left hand side here: 
http://demoleotheme.com/casper/index.php/?___store=default

Main Class

```
class Tm_StoreSettings_Model_Source_Types_Producttype
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 'layout_1', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Layout 1')),
            array('value' => 'layout_2', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Layout 2')),
            array('value' => 'layout_3', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Layout 3'))
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento comes with predefined store switcher. If you want to add custom dropdown you can do this in the file on this path: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml`. It is recommended that before changing you should copy this file to your theme on the same path as it is in `base/default` theme. You can add **HTML select** wherever you need it then in this file, like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```